# Double/triple domain redirection - Apache/IIS/Apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have issue with handling double domain redirection for 3 domains for my client.
1st domain in chain: domain1.com
2ns domain in chain: domain2.com
3rd domain in chain: domain3.com

Situation is like this:
 - For **domain1.com** I don't have DNS or any control panel access or FTP access and that domain have set redirection to **domain2.com**. My best guess that hosting company set redirection from vhost config file. As I can see from header answer, there is Apache installed.
 - **domain2.com** is controlled by me/client, with Wordpress site. Server is IIS/7.5 (shared hosting)
 - **domain3.com** is target site which should be finish point for traffic when visitors try to access domain1.com in browser. Also controlled by me/client. Server is Apache/2.4.7 (shared)

Q: I can point DNS for **domain2.com** to IP of **domain3.com** server, but then I will lost **domain2.com** Wordpress site. And all traffic is redirected to **domain3.com**.

How I can achieve that traffic which is initiated with http://domain1.com gets redirected to **domain3.com** but traffic initiated with http://domain2.com stay on **domain2.com** WP site.

Answer (score 0):

Place this function in functions.php file and call it each time user comes to your site :

```
<?php
    function check_visitor_domain(){
        $visitor_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        $url_details = parse_url($visitor_url);
        $domain = $url_details['host'];
        if($domain == 'domain1.com'){
            wp_redirect('http://domain3.com');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Will try this, only I was thought about some rewrite rules for that ;)
Like 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^domain1\.com$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com [R=301,L]`

but .htaccess not working in IIS... so will try to make IIS rewrite rules.

Only I'm not sure that HTTP_REFERER will have value of domain1.com if redirection is created from apache conf file on origin server.

Comment: Unfortunately, can't confirm it is working or not. Seems that 1st server in chain doesn't send HTTP_REFERER or IIS server doesn't allow to read that var. Anyway, visitor_url is always empty :(